# How to pass stored procedure parameter into cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to pass a parameter into cursor inside a stored procedure?

Here is a code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GenerateUpdates
    @DictionaryTable VARCHAR(50) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE
     @table_name VARCHAR(128) 
    ,@update_column VARCHAR(128) 
    ,@update_data VARCHAR(1024)
    ,@s VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE x CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT 
        table_name,
        column_name,
        UpdatedValue
    FROM
        @DictionaryTable

OPEN x;
FETCH NEXT FROM x INTO @table_name, @update_column, @update_data;

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    SET @s = '
            update ' + quotename(@table_name) + ' 
            set  ' + quotename(@update_column) + ' = ''' + @update_data + '''';
            
    BEGIN TRY
        --exec(@s); 
        PRINT (@s);
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT error_message()
    END CATCH;
    FETCH NEXT FROM x INTO @table_name, @update_column, @update_data;
END

CLOSE x;
DEALLOCATE x;

END
```

The `@DictionaryTable` parameter is not visible in the cursor. How I should modify the code to make the input parameter visible?

Comment: This has got [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/179361) written all over it. What exactly is it you are trying to achieve? To answer your question though, yes it is possible with dynamic SQL but this approach is at best flawed and prone to errors and inefficiencies and at worst it is dangerous and exposes your database to malicious SQL

Comment: He probably has a set of meta tables for doing *things* dynamically

Comment: @siggemannen you're right. I have tables names in the "Dictionary table" and I need to generate update for each of these tables

Comment: OK, but lets go back a step further, why are you  storing the updates in a dictionary table and writing a dynamic query to perform them? You are performing a crud action to store the updates, so why not just perform that action there and then rather than writing to a table to perform it dynamically? Why does that dictionary table need to be dynamically passed to the stored procedure, why not just read from that table? Or if you have many "dictionary" tables and need to read from one dynamically then why? Why not have a single dictionary table?

Comment: This essentially becomes dynamic-over-dynamic. I guess it might work if you do `DECLARE CURSOR` itself inside dynamic SQL and then pass back the open cursor, but never tried. I agree this whole thing is completely weird: you are doing *dynamic* updates to tables, with the dynamic list itself stored in a dynamic table, why?

Comment: This looks like a truly awful way of doing things. I agree with all the remarks from GarethD. Take it from two experts: don't do this.

Comment: I don't know guys, sometimes this kind of stuff is nice. For example, let's say you have some input table you want to clean i dunno, invalid characters from. Instead of hardcoding list of tables, you create a little cleaning system with dynamic table and columns. Sure, in a perfect world, the data is always perfect, but sometimes we don't live there

Comment: This screams of a design gone the wrong way. No matter what you come up with it is likely going to be extremely brittle and vulnerable to sql injection. Whenever you find yourself in a situation where the query is so difficult like this it is almost always an indication that something went haywire in the design.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have to create a cursor variable with dynamic sql.

Ie.

```sql
DECLARE @DictionaryTable sysname = 'sys.tables'
, @a sysname,@b sysname
declare @cr_x cursor
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'set @cr_x = CURSOR read_only forward_only static global for 
select name,
object_id
FROM ' + @DictionaryTable + N'

OPEN @cr_x -- Very important to open cursor inside dynamic sql!!
'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@cr_x cursor output', @cr_x = @cr_x output
while 1 = 1
begin
  fetch next from @cr_x into @a,@b
end
...
```

Note that you have to use a global cursor, and also you have to open it inside the dynamic sql

Comment: Don't you have to specifically declare the cursor scope as global? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: No, that's overkill in this case

Comment: I only ask (and I'm not a sql-server guy) because the manual says 'LOCAL
Specifies that the scope of the cursor is local to the batch, stored procedure, or trigger in which the cursor was created....'If neither GLOBAL or LOCAL is specified, the default is controlled by the setting of the default to local cursor database option.'

Comment: Ohh, i didn't know that. Just assumed it's always global unless specified. But yeah, in that case, you have to specify global to be on the safe side! Good catch